# Help! Ubuntu won't boot up!

Tags: boot, drivers, chromebook

I installed Ubuntu on my chromebook and all was working well until I tried installing steam. No games work because my graphics card was out of date so I tried installing intel driver update for Ubuntu, it opened but claimed that I didn't have a intel graphics card. I tried doing `apt-get update` in terminal but it said a bunch of stuff and then said "are you root?" so I did `sudo apt-get update` and it came with another error. I restarted my chrome book and attempted to start xfce4 until this popped up

```
/ $ sudo startxfce4
Entering /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...
/usr/bin/startxfce4: Starting X server

_XSERVTransmkdir: Owner of /tmp/.X11-unix should be set to root

X.Org X Server 1.11.3
Release Date: 2011-12-16
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.42-61-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux localhost 3.10.18 #1 SMP Fri Dec 11 19:13:56 PST 2015 x86_64
Kernel command line: cros_secure console= loglevel=7 init=/sbin/init cros_secure oops=panic panic=-1 root=/dev/dm-0 rootwait ro dm_verity.error_behavior=3 dm_verity.max_bios=-1 dm_verity.dev_wait=1 dm="1 vroot none ro 1,0 2506752 verity payload=PARTUUID=a426f256-534d-ba40-a9b8-ed38fc20733b/PARTNROFF=1 hashtree=PARTUUID=a426f256-534d-ba40-a9b8-ed38fc20733b/PARTNROFF=1 hashstart=2506752 alg=sha1 root_hexdigest=d810f4b5d34d05fb3f25e5b659467992216636df salt=43a025c4789be0386addcd863f295a8c95279dd6e3cb00fc3a476e8f409e60a8" noinitrd vt.global_cursor_default=0 kern_guid=a426f256-534d-ba40-a9b8-ed38fc20733b add_efi_memmap boot=local noresume noswap i915.modeset=1 tpm_tis.force=1 tpm_tis.interrupts=0 nmi_watchdog=panic,lapic  
Build Date: 12 February 2015  02:49:01PM
xorg-server 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.17 (For technical support please see ubuntu support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(++) Log file: "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.1.log", Time: Sat Dec 26 03:48:02 2015
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"

Fatal server error:
no screens found

Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
Please also check the log file at "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.1.log" for additional information.

 ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Now I can't go into my Ubuntu! Please help!

Answer (score 0):

On grub screen (if it does not show up automatically, you should press F2 or SHIFT+F2 on boot, if I am not wrong) choose Ubuntu recovery mode, then try to recover damaged packages (there is an on screen option). If this does not work, from the recovery mode open a root shell and install X11 (sudo apt-get install xorg)

Answer (score 0):

Start your computer, on login screen hit Ctl + Alt + F1

Login. Uninstall the desktop- 'sudo apt-get purge xfce4'

Install updates and upgrades: 'sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade'

Check for the latest kernel: 'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade'

Install all updates and upgrades.

Install xfce4 desktop : 'sudo apt-get install xfce4 && sudo apt-get upgrade xfce4'

Check all new packages 'sudo apt-get -f install'

Reboot and select xfce4 desktop. 'sudo reboot'